# How to let redis-semaphore queue "task_3" until "task_1" and "task_2" has been unlocked (rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, mutex, semaphore

**My situation:**

In my Rails application I am using **redis-semaphore** to ensure that recurring jobs don't stumble upon each other. I do it with these lines of code:

```
s1 = Redis::Semaphore.new(:task_1, connection: "localhost")

if s1.lock(-1)
  begin
    # Perform task_1
  rescue => e
    puts e
  ensure
    s1.unlock
  end
end
```

This all works just fine, so `:task_1` will be queued if there isn't already a `:task_1` in progress. And when the already running `:task_1` has been finished and unlocked, the queued `:task_1` will be started...

**My question:**

What if I am running 2 different tasks - let's call them `:task_1` and `:task_2` - and I now want to start a 3rd task - but I want to queue the 3rd task until `:task_1` and `:task_2` have been unlocked?

So far, I have tried the code below, where I check if `:task_1` and `:task_2` are running, and then only launches my 3rd task if none of them are running:

```
s1 = Redis::Semaphore.new(:task_1, connection: "localhost")
s2 = Redis::Semaphore.new(:task_2, connection: "localhost")

if s1.lock(-1) || s2.lock(-1)
  begin
    # Perform some task when task_1 and task_2 are both done
  rescue => e
    puts e
  ensure
    s1.unlock
    s2.unlock
  end
end
```

This code does lock properly - but it starts my 3rd task when either `:task_1` or `:task_2` unlocks. I want my 3rd task to wait until both `:task_1` and `:task_2` unlocked.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Does changing the condition from an "or" to an "and" help?

```
if s1.lock(-1) && s2.lock(-1)
```

Comment: No, because that then it only blocks if both are locked. But I need it to lock also if e.g. only `s1` is locked, but `s2` is unlocked.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding in case some one stubles upon this.

What might help is a countdown latch (set to count of 2 in your case). Task3 waits on the latch (e.g. `latch.await()`) and Task1 and Task2 execute `latch.countDown()` once they're done and that let's Task3 logic to proceed